# Modify Google chrome geolocation request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation, popup

I'm trying to modify the existing browser popup that is displayed when the website asks a user for a location permission. My code heavily relies on getting the user location so a small notification at the top of the screen that anyone hardly ever notices is quite a problem. Is it possible to ask for a location permission with JavaScript and display that message as a modal or a popup. If not in Chrome, do other browsers support it?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible! You can't modify the browsers native behaviour. You could however pop up a huge ass alert that tells the user to click the native confirm at the top of the browser.

Comment: I thought of that, but i secretly hoped there would be a more clever solution. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, something like this is as close as you'll get -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zwyf1ff4/**